# Retrieving Oracle db schema without admin roles to Sparx

Tags: oracle, odbc, database-schema, enterprise-architect

I'm trying to import db schema to sparx via odbc and I have a user without admin roles. It has access only on certain tables for monitoring database performance.

What minimal privileges my user should have to do this task? I know that I can retrieve user's schema, but I want to retrieve all schemas.

I hope there is no need for dba role or access to select all tables and dictionaries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acquire `SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE` to ger read access to data dictionary views. See details in [dokumentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBSEG/authorization.htm#DBSEG786)

Than use the query to get all schemas (i.e. all db users having some objects)

```
 select distinct owner from dba_objects;
```

To list all objects in a schema

```
 select * from dba_objects where owner = 'XXXX';
```

To get a column list of a table

```
 select * from dba_tab_columns where owner = 'XXX' and table_name = 'TTTTT' order by column_id;
```

Check [here](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/REFRN/static-data-dictionary-views-2.htm#REFRN-GUID-88C6BCB4-5D86-47A3-AD27-F7AA7EDD9FDC) the dictionary view.

Note that with the privilege `SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE` you see only the metadata, you have no access to data (tables or views).

Comment: It didn't help me, I see system tables schemas that is visible to all users. But actually I need to see all users schemas without access to data.

Comment: Added the dictionary view you should query to see the definition (metadata) of database objects of all users.

Comment: well maybe I mis-read you question. If you want to export **data** from Oracle- this will not help. I assumed you are interested in the **metadata**, i.e. table structure etc.

Comment: I need to import db schemas to sparx ea for creating diagrams, but I don't see all schemas after importing in the program. However, I can see metadata and can do the commands you typed.

Comment: Thank you Marmite! I tried to import schemas to Oracle SQL Developer Data Modeler and using a user with just this role I got all schemas!

Answer (score 0):

Edited from discussion below (thanks for response):

> CREATE SESSION
>
> DATAPUMP_EXP_FULL_DATABASE
>
> SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE
>
> RESOURCE

And selected privileges from DATAPUMP_IMP_FULL_DATABASE since you don't want permission to select any table.

You can get this list from

```
select privilege 
from dba_sys_privs 
where grantee = 'DATAPUMP_IMP_FULL_DATABASE';
```

Comment: The `connect` privilege is deprecated, you should use `create session` instead

Comment: Sparx is (basically) a data modelling tool. EXP_FULL_DATABASE and IMP_FULL_DATABASE are wildly over-powerful for this.

Comment: usually they say 1 schema, and then it becomes a whole bunch of repositories and what not... with these third party installations I give their installer DBA privs on dev and test and make sure they connect only via their installer

Comment: EXP_FULL_DATABASE and IMP_FULL_DATABASE are really over powerful. Maybe DATAPUMP_EXP_FULL_DATABASE? The data in tables is secret and this user must not have an access to view it or export it.

Comment: Marcus in that case then the DATAPUMP roles are better.  Also RESOURCE for the creates and maybe CREATE USER.  You can check what each role has with : select privilege from dba_sys_privs where grantee = 'RESOURCE'